# Angular File Upload with Parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I'm using [Angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload#bower) to upload files to an API by doing this:

```
var upload = function (file) {
    return $upload.upload({
        url: '/api/place/logo',
        data: {place_id: 1, token: <some_token>},
        file: file
    });
};
```

All the parameters seem to be correctly set. The API expects the `token` to be present for authentication. For some reason, the API never receives the `token` or the `place_id` posted by the client and always responds with a `BadRequest`.

What is the issue here?

Comment: token should not be part of data, it should be part of header, if i m not mistaken

Comment: @HarishR in an ideal scenario, yes. But we're first writing a viable RESTful API that can work across clients without much hassle. Using the token as part of the data is more straightforward, imho.

Comment: what would be hassels, you could face if you pass the token as part of header? in fact most of the client do agree to have token in header

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

At angular controller:

```
.controller('uploadCtrl', function ($scope, FileUploader) {
    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: "./api/file/upload",
        formData: [
            { "data1": "value1" },
            { "data2": "value2" }
        ]
    });
});
```

At server side(In FileController, method: upload):

```
var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

var data1 = result.FormData.Get("data1");
var data2 = result.FormData.Get("data2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Bearer token? I'm using the https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload and ran into a similar problem, turns out the file post was occurring using AJAX and not the $http, so the authorisation interceptor service (which is supposed to inject the token into all outgoing traffic from my angular website) wasn't working.

Depending on how your library works, you might be running into a similar issue. If so, you have to specify the token as the 'Authorization' header, something along the lines of (where I am retrieving authData from localStorage after having been authorized previously by the token provider):

```
tokenHeader = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    headers: { "Authorization": tokenHeader },
    url: _uploadUrl,
    withCredentials: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like this:

```
var tokenHeader = $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;

var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: '/api/WS_Books/PostBooks',
    autoUpload: true,
    headers: { "Authorization": tokenHeader },
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onBeforeUploadItem method to inject jwt token

```
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
      item.headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token_name')
       };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This here worked for me. I'm using PHP

You can send values ​​to PHP using the formData property

```
app.controller ('FileUploadCtrl', ['$ scope', 'FileUploader', 
function ($ scope, FileUploader) {
var uploader = $ scope.uploader = new FileUploader ({
    url: '.myapi / mycontrollers / myuploadfile.php',
    formData: [{
             data1: 'value1',
             data2: 'value2',
             dataN: 'valueN'
           }]
});
```

In PHP you use $ _REQUEST to capture the information available in formData

```
$myValue1 = $_REQUEST ['data1'];
$myValue2 = $_REQUEST ['data2'];
$myValue3 = $_REQUEST ['dataN'];
```